# "Too many arguments" error in the command "cat"

Tags: bash, cat

I have 2 Ubuntu machines on which the command `cat` behaves differently.

```
Machine A
Linux foo 4.15.0-191-generic #202-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 01:49:29 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
cat (GNU coreutils) 8.28
```

```
Machine B
Linux foo 4.4.0-31-generic #50~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 01:07:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
cat (GNU coreutils) 8.21
```

On Machine A, `cat` prints `-sh: [: too many arguments` by

```
cat<<EOF
EOF
```

or

```
cat<<EOF
hello world
EOF
```

On Machine B, the commands don't print the error. However, `cat somefile` does not raise the error on both machines.

On Machine A, a made-up command raises the error too.

```
fakecommand<<EOF
EOF
```

which prints

```
-sh: fakecommand: command not found
-sh: [: too many arguments
```

On Machine B, the made-up command prints

```
fakecommands: command not found
```

So far as I know, the "too many arguments" error is mostly related with `if`. In my case, it seems some shell script is invoked by `command<<EOF` like a hook. I don't know what it could be.

Thanks for any clue.

Comment: This is almost certainly not being caused by the command itself, but by something in your shell configuration/customization -- maybe something in your prompt string or `PROMPT_COMMAND`, or a trap, or something like that.

Comment: As for WHY the errors at all, I am tempted to say that you have different default SHELL values on each computer.  Maybe bash on one and ksh on another.  That might influence the behaviour.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks a lot. Machine A has `PROMPT_COMMAND` set and Machine B does not. After running `unset PROMPT_COMMAND`, the issue is gone. I'll find out where it's defined. Would you please write an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: This is neither related to `cat` nor to `bash`. You can see from the wording of the error message, that you don't have bash as a shell, but sh.  I would, as a first step, try to find out what shell (and version) is really running on MachineA, or, if you don't want to research deeper and simply want things going quickly, ensure that you really run _bash_ on both machines. BTW, you can check which bash you are running, by doing a `echo $BASH_VERSION`.